# Angular 6 nav list items

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

> `private commands = ['Comand1, Comand2, Comand3'];`

```
    <div class="basic-container">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item (click)="menuTrigger.openMenu()" *ngFor="let i of commands">
          <div mat-line>
            {{ i }}
          </div>
          <p mat-line>
            {{ i }}
          </p>
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </div>
```

I want items to be sorted one below another.

Cimmand1

---

Cimmand2

---

Cimmand3

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to put new line for each of your loop output,

```
 <div class="basic-container">
  <mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item (click)="menuTrigger.openMenu()" *ngFor="let i of commands">
      <div mat-line>
        <p>{{i}}</p><hr/> <!--like this-->
      </div>
      <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-nav-list>
</div>
```

UPDATE: The issue was actually related with array definition,

```
private commands = ['Comand1', 'Comand2', 'Comand3'];
```